# Unable to add array to firebase-firestore in reactjs?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to send a list of arrays to Firestore using a variable called **array_list** but when I check my firebase console the array is present but the value inside of it is empty.

```
let array_list = [];
let user_id = localStorage.getItem("userId");

function add_data() {
    let i = 0;
    for(i;i<10;i++){
         array_list.push(i);      
       }
   }

add_data()
let db = firebase.firestore();
if (user_id !== null) {
    var doc = db.collection("users").doc(user_id);
  }

const sendHistData = () => {
    console.log("Creating Database...");
    doc
      .set({
        browsingHistory: array_list,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

if(user_id!==null){
   add_data();
   sendHistData();
}
```

Here is the link to the [full code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ouCjdlNYndAo22nvXs5F0bQO7OdtXiFA/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the screenshot [image: screenshot]

Comment: How is `user_id` initialized?

Comment: ```user_id``` is the firebase anonymous account's user-id

Comment: Thanks, but please edit your question to show the code that initializes `user_id` and how it related to the code you already shared.

Answer (score 0):

The var "doc" seems to be undefined in your sendHistData function. Try refactoring the function:

```
let db = firebase.firestore();

const sendHistData = () => {
    // if (!user_id) return null // user not logged in
    const db = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user_id)
    console.log("Creating Database...");
    doc
      .set({
        browsingHistory: array_list,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Also you are checking if user_id is null or not before calling the function so verifying that again inside of the function is redundant.

Comment: Dharmaraj the array is being added in the document but its value is empty. I have edited the post you can take a look at it.

Comment: @AyushKumar can you please try `console.log(array_list)` just before `console.log("Creating database")` ? I doubt if it's scope issue similar to what you had with var doc. Does it log the complete array or empty?

Comment: Yes I have logged the array_list and it shows the values, but I don't know why the values are not being added to the firestore.

Comment: @AyushKumar  can you share some more code? Maybe like the parent function or so?

Comment: @AyushKumar where have you initialized Firebase? Also hardcoding array isn't working either?